# chi-square as scoring function for regression

Tags: machine-learning, regression, scikit-learn, feature-selection

It is documented in http://scikit-learn.org/0.9/modules/feature_selection.html
"**Warning** Beware not to use a regression scoring function with a classification problem."

I am trying to find the best features for a regression problem and using f_regression as the scoring function. But it is extremely Memory hungry and my 8GB machine hangs and finally I get Memory error.

I have used Chi2 as a scoring function for the same problem and it works very fast. Wanted to know **if the reverse of the warning is true** ? If not can I use **Chi2** as a scoring function for regression problem ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The χ² test builds a contingency table of `n_classes` times `n_features`. In a regression model, there is no notion of `n_classes`. The only way to make it work would be to bin your `y` values, do feature selection, then train a regression model on the original `y` and the reduced feature set. There is no support for this in scikit-learn, so you'll have to program it yourself.

Comment: This seems reasonable to me... is there any module in scikit that would _bin_ my y values ? or do i have to write my own ?

Comment: @user644745: you'd have to write your own.

Answer (score 1):

No you should not use Chi2 scoring function as it has no proved guarantee to be accurate for regression model. You have to check your f_regression solution or use other solution like recursive elimination or PCA(Principle Component Analysis)

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principal_component_analysis

I personally would advice PCA, it gives very robust results.

Comment: Thanks Vikram. I do not want to use PCA, as it would reduce the dimension. I want to select the best features.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest you use LASSO if your problem is regression. Lasso is just standard regression with L1 regularization baked in; this has the effect of driving many feature weights to zero.

[Scikit has an implementation of Lasso](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.Lasso.html).